# Printing something at the end of a gets input in ruby

Tags: ruby, printing, terminal, line

In Ruby, how can you add something that displays at the end of a user's `gets` input on the same line?

Something like this:

```
puts "What is your favorite quote? Please write below:"
print "\""
gets.strip
print "\"" # idealy displaying on the same line as gets
puts "great!"
```

But with this output in the terminal:

```
What is your favorite quote? Please write below:
"xyz quote"
great!
```

Comment: it's a bit difficult because the newline character is used to finish the `gets` ...

Comment: `"My dog #{gets.chomp} likes other dogs"` displays `My dog Saffi likes other dogs` when I enter `"Saffi"`. is that what you mean?

Comment: @CarySwoveland not really, like it would be great if it a character could follow after the input on the same line, not print the input on a line below

Comment: You’d probably need Readline or HighLine, and would have to stuff `””` into the input buffer and move the cursor in between your quotes. I sincerely doubt it’s worth the trouble, and won’t handle all sorts of edge cases, but that would be a potential approach.

Answer (score 0):

[`require 'io/console'`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-getch) to get fine-grained control over input. For example inside a `STDIN.noecho { ... }` block, you can prevent the return key from printing a new line in the terminal. However it also prevents all other characters from printing, which may be confusing. But you can use `STDIN.getch` to get input character-by-character rather than line-by-line and manually echo the characters you do want to show. The trick there is handling unprintable keys like backspace or ctrl, which you will need to manually program to perform the correct action on the input.

It's a surprising amount of work to implement the behavior you want correctly. Carefully consider whether it is actually worth it.

Comment: Hello, Max. LTNS.

Answer (score 0):

> [H]ow can you add something that displays at the end of a user's gets input on the same line?

Don't conflate your input with the way you want to represent your output. It's much easier to treat them differently. First, retrieve the user's input. Second, sanitize and format the output the way you want.

The following class is flexible enough that it won't care if the user's input is quoted or not; it also won't care whether the input line contains escaped double-quotes.

```rb
class Quote
  def initialize
    get_quote
    quote_the_quote
  end

  # get quote from user and adjust quotes on input
  def get_quote
    print 'What is your favorite quote? '

    # remove starting/ending double-quotes, remove escapes, and
    # convert internal double-quotes to single-quotes
    @quote = gets.chomp.gsub(/\A"|"\z/, '').delete('\\').tr(?", ?')
  end

  def quote_the_quote
    @quote = ?" + @quote + ?"
  end

  def print_quote
    puts "Selected quote: #{@quote}"
  end
end

Quote.new.print_quote
```

Your interaction will then look like this:

> ```
> What is your favorite quote? 'Twas brillig and the slithy toves...
> Selected quote: "'Twas brillig and the slithy toves..."
> ```

So, you won't have the added quotes in your input line (which could be problematic anyway if the user adds quotes directly), but you can certainly store them in your *@quote* variable, or print them on standard output when printing the quote. Differentiating your input from your output will also enable you to Do the Right Thing℠ with more complex inputs, such as:

- `This is "complicated."`
- `"foo "bar" baz"`
- `"quux \"wibble\" wobble"`

There are bound to be edge cases, so you may need to make additional changes based on your expected input. This should definitely get you started, though!